# How can I access a BCL class or property inline in a aspx page in .NET 1.1?

Tags: asp.net, .net-1.1, inline-code

Its been a while since I worked in asp.net and a very long time since working in .NET 1.1. Here I am though in a legacy application that I can't upgrade for the short term, and I need to fix a number of hard coded values and replace them with a value from my web.config file.

This is what I have:

```
<asp:Image id=Image1 runat="server" ImageUrl='http://<%# ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CorporateRootUrl"] %>/media/images/spacer.gif' width="16" height="10" />

<img src='http://<%# ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CorporateRootUrl"] %>/media/images/spacer.gif' width="16" height="10" runat="server">
```

I would PREFER to get the bottom example to pull from my web.config file, since that is what is used throughout this application, and it would make my life a ton easier.

I can pull the "CorporateRootUrl" value if I use it in the .cs code behind, but that doesn't really help me. I have over 2500 places I need to change in this code.

I am SURE I am missing something simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Yea, I am used to .NET 3.5SP1 and now .NET 4, and this project has given me a newfound appreciation for what MS has done with .NET in the last few years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img src="http://<% = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CorporateRootUrl"] %>/media/images/spacer.gif" width="16" height="10">
```

The # in your inline code, and the runat=server were the simple things tripping you up.

Fortunately for you, I had a old 1.1 project open that I could reference. We weren't doing the same thing as you need to, but my 1.1 is rusty too and looking at the code is helping me get some of it back.

Good luck with the rest of your assignment!

Comment: WOW I was close. I added the runat=server because I thought that might be my problem. Turns out I just needed the = ( equals ) sign.  Thanks a ton, I have spent way too much time trying to figure this out.